# Wordpress .htaccess redirects file extension and case-insensitive

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, case-sensitive, file-extension

I am moving a website to wordpress but I want to keep the current URL structure for SEO purposes.

The current site uses a combination of .htm and .html files. I found success in redirecting to .htm when the request is .html.

For example

```
    RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\wp-site/mywebpage.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/wp-site/mywebpage.htm
```

I have trouble with the following:

when the .html file has upper and lower case. I can't seem to find a solution to redirect any request despite the case to its .htm equivalent

For example: My-Posts/Alpha-Page.html needs to redirect to my-posts/alpha-page.htm or MY-POSTS/ALPHA-PAge.html redirects to my-posts/alpha-page.htm (or any of "my-posts/alpha-page" that contains uppercase. basically all requests despite case needs to redirect to all lowercase .htm file)

I know it's a little difficult because it's a combination 1) I'm redirecting to .htm and 2) for the case insensitivity.

Few things to consider:

1. I know Wordpress posts are
   case-insensitive. Wordpress's static
   page are case-sensitive.
2. I know RedirectMatch won't work
   because it matches it exactly.
3. I believe I need to use RewriteCond
   and RewriteRule, but can't seem to
   find "good" step by step
   explanations. Also, I don't
   understand their variables (ie:
   %{HTTP_HOSTS}) and the regular
   expression convention.
4. I am not an Apache/.htaccess or
   regular expressions expert by any
   means.

Theoretically, it seems there should be a way for it to work. I will continue to see if I can find solutions here at stackoverflow or other outside resources and if I do find a solution here at stackoverflow, I will marked this as solved and have it removed.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

UPDATE 06/17/2011:

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
    # BEGIN WordPress

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteBase /wp-test-2011-06-13/

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /wp-test-2011-06-13/index.php


    RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\wp-test-2011-06-13/redirect.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/wp-test-2011-06-13/redirect.htm


    RewriteRule ^ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME.html$ /orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]


    </IfModule>


    # END WordPress
```

UPDATE 06/20/2011:

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /wp-test-2011-06-13/
    RewriteRule ^/wp-test-2011-06-13/index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* /wp-test-2011-06-13/index.php 

    RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\wp-test-2011-06-13/redirect.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/wp-test-2011-06-13/redirect.htm

    RewriteRule ^ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME\.html$ /orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

I get a Wordpress "Page Not Found" page when I type http://www.mydomain.com/wp-test-2011-06-13/ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME.html (or lowercase equivalent with .html)

Comment: As I understand you want: 1) change file extension in final url from html to htm; 2) ignore the case when redirecting .. or change final page URL to a lower case?

Comment: 1) Yes. Change the request of .html to redirect to .htm
2) I believe I want to ignore case. 

MYPAGE.html --> mypage.htm, or mYPaGe.html --> mypage.htm, or MYpaGE.html --> mypage.htm, etc...

basically ignoring the case of the request and redirecting to the lower case .htm version

Comment: I thought something like this might work.

`code` RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^section/individual-page.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/wp-install/section/individual-page.htm/$1 [L,R=301]

I think I'm on the right track. [NC] should ignore case right?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you can "easily" do this with the help of mod_rewrite .. **BUT** these instructions **need to be placed in a config file** (inside `<VirtualHost>` tag) as `RewriteMap` directive cannot be used in .htaccess unfortunately.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap upper2lower int:tolower
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.html$ /${upper2lower:$1}.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]
```

2) If you cannot modify config file, then you can do at least redirect `html` to `htm`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]
```

There are few more options that can be used with .htaccess:

3) Create rewrite rule for each of such pages -- quite inefficient and requires constant updating (new rule for every new page) -- case does not matter here:

```
RewriteRule ^MYPAGES/some-Page.html$ /mypages/some-page.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]
```

4) Make 2-step redirect: 1) redirect html to some special php file, which when executed redirects to a proper lower-cased URL. Doable .. but ugly (plus 2 redirects involved).

If you cannot do #1, then stick with #2 and make sure you are using `<link rel="canonical" href="PROPER_URL_GOES_HERE"/>` in your `<header>`.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the reply. Is it possible to just utilize step 3? I don't mind redirecting all the individual pages as long as it ignores case and redirects .html to .htm. I tried just placing step 3) in my .htaccess and it does't seem to work. Does the order of my statements matter? Redirecting .html to .htm doesn't need to happen to all requests; it can be specific pages (or in this case, posts).

Comment: Those are not steps but options (separate from each other). But Yes, you can go with #3 only. Yes, order matters. Please show your current .htaccess (edit your original question) -- I would like to see where you are trying to insert new directives.

Comment: OK, I see your update: move all such redirect rules (`RewriteRule ^ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME.html$ /orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]`) just after (or just before) this rule: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Comment: I did what you suggested. No luck. I did it after and before. Would the parameters in the brackets [] need to change?

Comment: Which rule you have in mind (about [] brackets)? They all look OK. I think it has something to do with this line `RewriteBase /wp-test-2011-06-13/` - it may affect all rules. You need to "debug" it a bit to see what is going on. Try adding this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php&apth=$1&uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301]` just below `RewruteBase` rule (this is temporarily). If it doesn't work then try add `/wp-test-2011-06-13/` before index.php. Go to any url that you want to redirect and post which URL will you see in address bar after this rule kicks in (sorry, there is no easy to use debugger).

Comment: I can assure you that the rules have been tested and are working. The only thing right now that I can think of why they are not working on your side is the effect of `RewriteBase` rule. You need to investigate it a bit. I can help with advice/ideas .. but cannot do it instead of you from over here.

Comment: I don't believe the problems I'm encountering have to do with `RewriteBase /wp-test-2011-06-13/` (This defines my root folder for my wordpress files and index.php).

Do you know what the following lines mean?


`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-test-2011-06-13/index.php`

I think I might have to remove, alter, or place line before/after somewhere in those lines.

Comment: First rewrite rule tells to do nothing if `/index.php` is requested. Second rule should rewrite all requests to `/wp-test-2011-06-13/index.php` if requested resource (file or directory) does not exist. TBH I'm not sure about `.` part -- I would use `.*` at least. I still think (well, that is the only thing I can do in this case from overhere) that there must be an issue with rules order or folder paths.

Comment: The rule `RewriteRule ^ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME.html$ /orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]`, can you add a slash before dot in first half of the rule -- make it like this: `RewriteRule ^ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME\.html$ /orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]`

Comment: I am more than convinced that the answer lies in how the RewriteRule is written/placed. More specifically, the TestString and how it's written: `^ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME\.html$` The format of the string? The file extension at the end?

Comment: The rule is spelled correctly -- works absolutely fine on my PC. Position in .htaccess -- yes, but you already said that you put it quite on top (can you update post with current positions, please). As I already have mentioned I'm unsure about paths (the way how this one (`/wp-test-2011-06-13/`) can affect the whole thing). Look at comment #5 here -- can you do that rule and show where you will be redirected to?

Comment: I've tried adding and removing directories extensions, repositioning rules. Pretty much trying different combination of rewriting I can think of. Most of the time I get a Wordpress "page not found" page. I also (depending on what I changed and where) I get a 500 server error or a 301 moved permanently error by Apache.

You can take a look at my latest update. But I am continually changing my .htaccess to see if I get lucky.

Comment: This sort of Rewrite Rule should be **BEFORE** first RewriteCond (as these 3 instructions tell Apache to redirect all unknown URLs to index.php). Also, please try RewriteRule without leading `^` , e.g. `RewriteRule ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME\.html$ /orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]` as well as this variant: `RewriteRule ORLANDO-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-NEJAME\.html$ /wp-test-2011-06-13/orlando-criminal-defense-attorney/defense-attorney-nejame.htm [QSA,NC,R=301]`

Comment: Tried several different combinations. The only thing that I can think of that could be interfering is that I have a Wordpress plugin that places .htm to all of posts and pages. But the RedirectMatch 301 works, so I'm not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: I do not know then, sorry. I can only assure you that the rule itself is working. I have not worked with WordPress directly and don't know pretty much anything about plugins it can have and how they may affect the redirection here.